# Encoding issue when running python script from crontab

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, cron

I am migrating my python scripts from one server to a new docker container. But I am facing a strange issue with encoding, I tried several solutions without success.

If I run the script directly from the terminal (manually) it is executed with success. But if I run through crontab I get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

I created a small script just to check the encoding:

```
import sys
print sys.stdout.encoding
```

If I run manually I get the following response:

> UTF-8

Then, I added this script in cron and directed the output to a file:

```
 * * * * *   /tmp/p.py > /tmp/p.log
```

It saved a empty p.log... So I think that python is not getting the encode from the crontab.

I saw a several suggestions to add in crontab the encoding variables before call the command, but it not worked for me. 
for exemple:

```
* * * * *  PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 /tmp/p.py > /tmp/p.log
```

or

```
* * * * *  LANG=UTF-8 /tmp/p.py > /tmp/p.log
```

Also, I tried to added this variables in the head of my crontab file. No success at all.

I am using Ubuntu with few locales installed:

```
    locale -a 
    C 
    C.UTF-8 
    en_US.utf8 
    POSIX
```

And here is my locale (outside cron):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have several python scripts running, so it's not a good idea to edit them (also, as I said its running perfectly when called outside cron).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it was some problem with crontab, it wasn't reload automatically when the file was edited.

To force the reload I did:

```
crontab /etc/crontab
```

and

```
service cron restart
```

Now the crontab is loading correctly the environment variables. In the header of crontab file have the following variables:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

TERM=xterm
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Lifesaver, I've been blocked on this for hours! Thanks a lot for your answer!